# Setting alias in ipython

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

Currently I am debugging a script of myself in maestro. The problem is i always have to load all the scripts manually with %run in the ipython shell.

I tried to set it up with alias_magic, but I am somehow lost because it seems nobody is setting up multiline aliases in ipython.

```
In [13]: %alias_magic sitemap_gui --cell %run /home/eggerluk/python_code    /SiteMapAggregator/philipp_orginal/cfg.py \
...: %run  /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/ligand_tracker/ligandtracker.py \
...: %run /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/gui/sitemapaggregator_utils.py \
...: %run /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/philipp_orginal/binding_sites.py \
...: %run /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/philipp_orginal/Visualization.py \
...: %run /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/philipp_orginal/sitemap_aggregator.py 
...: 
...: %run /home/eggerluk/python_code/SiteMapAggregator/sitemapaggregator_gui.py
...:
```

I would like to execeute with %sm_gui all run commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did not really solve my question but I sorted the problem out with the help of this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html) and trying to understand the concept of imports in python. I had to restructure some modules but now a single `%run` command in the ipython shell does the trick.

Hope it helps anybody.